# Python Barcode Generation

Tags: python, barcode, ghostscript, elaphe

I'm using the elaphe package for python to generate ean-13 barcode images. The package was installed from source using the tar file found at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elaphe.

When I run the code:

```
BARCODE_IMAGE_PATH = "/tmp/"

def create_barcode_image(product_barcode):

    path = BARCODE_IMAGE_PATH + product_barcode + '.png'

    img = barcode('ean13', product_barcode, 
                  options=dict(includetext=True, height=0.4), margin=1)
    img.save(path, 'PNG')

    return path
```

from the python interpreter it seems to work perfectly. The correct barcode is generated to the path that I specify. When I run it from apache using web.py as my web framework I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
     img_path = create_barcode_image(barcode)
   File "/var/www/py/documents/barcode_images.py", line 27, in create_barcode_image
     img.save(path, 'PNG')
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1406, in save
     self.load()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 283, in load
     self.im = Ghostscript(self.tile, self.size, self.fp)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 75, in Ghostscript
     raise IOError("gs failed (status %d)" % status)
 IOError: gs failed (status 256)
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this error or how to go about debugging it?

Comment: are these on the same machine?  If not, are you sure you have ghost script installed on the web-server?

Comment: Yup, I ran it on the same machine and ghostscript is installed. I've even became the www-data user and ran it that way which worked as well. I've been scratching my head all day over this one.

Comment: iirc, these things (webservers running scripts) tend to get run with really restricted environmental variables, you may have a path issue. (Also, I think error 256 is really error -1 laundered through a uint.

Answer (score 1):

Add in some debug statements that you can walk through:

```
import sys

BARCODE_IMAGE_PATH = "/tmp/"

def create_barcode_image(product_barcode):

    print >> sys.stderr, "product_barcode: %s" % product_barcode

    path = BARCODE_IMAGE_PATH + product_barcode + '.png'

    print >> sys.stderr, "path: %s" % path

    img = barcode('ean13', product_barcode, 
                  options=dict(includetext=True, height=0.4), margin=1)

    print >> sys.stderr, "img data: %s" % img.tostring()

    img.save(path, 'PNG')

    print >> sys.stderr, "Saved to %s" % path

    return path
```

Then in your shell:

```
$ tail -F /var/log/httpd/error.log # or wherever you put it
```

You're looking for: First: the output of "`product_barcode: ...`". Hopefully that's not blank. If it is, then the problem lies elsewhere, maybe in your server config. Then the output of "`img data: ...`". Hopefully it's a png and not blank. If it's blank, then the problem lies with your ghostscript installation.

This is a very rudimentary way of debugging, and I feel that for small projects it is just as easy to throw in some debug statements rather than messing around with the debugger, which can be difficult to set up properly.

Comment: This helps a lot. I was never sure how to print when using a web server. I always ended up creating a log database which slows the application down a lot. Everything seems to point back to GhostScript so I'll try re-installing it. I just find it odd why it works normally but not on the web server. I couldn't find any issues with the paths that would make it fail.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace suggests that the image returned by `barcode()` is PostScript. PIL then tries to run GhostScript (`gs`) to convert the image to the desired output format `PNG`.

If you look into the [description of elaphe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elaphe), you see that it says:

> It generates barcode symbol as PostScript code fragment using BWIPP.

Do you have GhostScript installed?

That said, I suggest you try [pyBarcode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyBarcode/0.7) instead since it doesn't have any dependency besides PIL.

Comment: GhostScript has definitely been installed. I'll double check to make sure it's completely up to date and working correctly. I was using pyBarcode initially but moved to elaphe since the text format along the bottom of the barcode seems to be the standard layout.

Comment: It would be nice if PIL would print the output of `gs`; it probably doesn't fail silently. If you can, edit the source code and add some logging / debugging info (like the arguments that were used to call `gs`).

Answer (score -1):

This error can be caused if `barcode` is invalid. You should first make sure it is what you expect. eg. print it out, or write it to a file or use the debugger

Comment: When the question specifically includes "or how to go about debugging it?", telling OP to "use the debugger" is not helpful at all.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, are you suggesting that the debugger is not useful for debugging? The important part it to check that `barcode` is valid. I simply suggested 3 ways to check it

Comment: I'm suggesting that your answer does not teach a person to use the debugger or check that barcode is valid.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, of course it doesn't. That would be way out of the scope of the question. I don't know Stuart's experience level, so I suggested to use `print` first.